# How can I show JSON response in my Snackbar?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

After login I successfully got response from my api also can print the Data in my second screen by doing this `Text("Status: ${widget.rresponse.status}"),` .
But I want to print in snackbar.

**What will be the the syntax to print json response data in my SnackBar?**

Here is my Json response

```
    {
    "Status": "1",
    "Message": "You are Logged in successfully",
    "UserData": {
        "Name": "qwerty@gmail.com",
        "EncUserId": "GO9gj3aSUKCpxE3AMSbh/A=="
    }
}
```

My Api got call when user press the login button

```
 Future<void> login() async{
var jsonResponse;
if (passwordontroller.text.isNotEmpty && emailController.text.isNotEmpty) {
  var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://ututututtutu"),
      body: ({
        'LoginId': emailController.text,
        'Password': passwordontroller.text
      }));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     print("Correct");
     print(response.body);
     jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
     print(jsonResponse);
   // ===========Successfully can print in my second screen ================== 
   // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>AfterLoginResPage(rresponse: ApiResponse.fromJson(jsonResponse))));

  //===========Trying to print in my snackBar========================

   jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());//==
     ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content:Text("Message: ${jsonResponse['encUserId']}"))) ;   
  }
  
  
  
  
  
  
   else {
    print("Wronggooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
    print(response.body);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Invalid credentials")));
  }
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Blank field is not allowed")));
}

  }
```

And Here is my `Model` class

```
class ApiResponse {
ApiResponse({
    required this.status,
    required this.message,
    required this.userData,
});

String status;
String message;
UserData? userData; 



   factory ApiResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ApiResponse(
        status: json["Status"],
        message: json["Message"],
        userData: json["UserData"] == null? null:UserData.fromJson(json["UserData"] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    );


}

class UserData {
    UserData({
        required this.name,
        required this.encUserId,
    });

String name;
String encUserId;

factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserData(
    name: json["Name"],
    encUserId: json["EncUserId"],
);
```

Comment: Case sensitive.
"EncUserId" != "encUserId"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case sensitive. "EncUserId" != "encUserId"

Comment: Can I also display this in my App drawer after user login?

Comment: like , somhow can I save this response in variable so that I can use it anywhere in my app in `Text()` form?

Comment: Yes, you can use a local storage like Hive local database, or you can send the by parameter on page navigation.